# Button shakes on hover

Tags: css

I'm having trouble while hovering my buttons. They seem to shake when the mouse is not entirely over the button.

I've made a JSFiddle so you can see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/h93jkxck/

I've tried to give it a `min-height` but it's still shaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because they change their position on hover, so actually the are not hovered anymore... and it looks like they were "shaking"

try this:

```css
.btn-social{
  color: #000;
  margin-top:0em;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: .75em;
  padding-right: .75em;
  font-size: .85em;
}
.hover-helper:hover{
  padding-top: 1em;
}
div{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-helper"><button class='btn-social'>Facebook</button></div>
<div class="hover-helper"><button class='btn-social'>Google</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when the button is `hover` the button tries to get `1em` margin so it makes the button `shake`.
make `margin-top:0em;` like this

```
.btn-social:hover{
    margin-top: 0em;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: But if I do this, then my hover doesn't work. He needs to have 1em to change position.

Comment: @Greg the above only makes button to stop shaking. after this when you apply another property like giving background color like `background-color:red;` than it works

Answer (score 1):

When you hover the button the give :hover style is applied

```
.btn-social:hover {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Also that made the mouseout event as the button goes beyond the mouse. So the style is reverted and hover fires again. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h93jkxck/3/ You can remove the margin and add some other styles in the :hover section

Answer (score 1):

You're applying a margin top when the mouse is hovered over the link.

This is without the margin top.

http://jsfiddle.net/h93jkxck/1/

```
.btn-social{
    color: #000;
    margin-top:0em;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: .75em;
    padding-right: .75em;
    font-size: .85em;
    }
div{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of margins. Your buttons loses hover when got it. Here is solution:
html:

```
<div class="hover"><button class='btn-social'>Facebook</button></div>
<div class="hover"><button class='btn-social'>Google</button></div>
```

css:

```
    .btn-social{
        color: #000;
        margin-top:0em;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: .75em;
        padding-right: .75em;
        font-size: .85em;
    }
.hover:hover{
    padding-top: 1em;
}
div{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h93jkxck/2/